$\mathbb E(X_1 X_2|Y)$ when $Y = X_1 + \cdots + X_n$
Find $\mathbb E(X_1 X_2|Y)$ when $Y = X_1 + \cdots + X_n$ for a Bernoulli distribution for coin flipping with $n$ flips. Here heads = $1$, and tails = $0$.
I understand that $X_1 X_2$ equals $1$ if and only if both are heads and equals $0$ otherwise. I also understand that on the condition $Y$ where $Y$ is the number of heads in $n$ flips, we are looking for the expectation that the first two flips are heads. I am confused about computing the expectation.

Write the conditional expectation $E(Y^2|Y)$ in two different ways, and exploit symmetry and linearity of expectation.

I have E(Y^2|Y)=Y^2 given that Y=y and Y^2 is calculated on this. I also have E(Y^2|Y)=∑ᵧ(y^2)(P(Y=y|Y)), this also simplifies to Y^2 as well, no?

Given the problem, it would make sense to try and rewrite it in terms of the $X_i$ as well.

Why not just do it explicitly / by definition?  There are $ { n \choose Y}$ cases for there to be $Y$ heads. How many cases are there with $X_1 = X_2 = 1$? Hence, what is the probability for $P(X_1X_2) = 1$, and thus what is $E(X_1X_2)$?

Note that $Y$ is a complete sufficient statistic.   Because
$$
EY^2 = p^2n(n-1)+EY
$$
it follows that $(Y^2-Y)/(n(n-1))$ is the UMVUE for $p^2$. Because, $X_1X_2$ is an unbiased estimator of $p^2$ for each $i$, Lehmann scheffe and rao blackwell imply that
$$
E(X_1X2\mid Y) = \frac{Y^2-Y}{n(n-1)}.
$$
